# Control plot appearance in vtk / Qt

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I display a vtk surface plot inside a QVTKWidget. The QVTKWidget supports interaction, i.e., I can e.g. zoom or rotate. 
I would like to control the initial appearance of the plot before any user interaction: Zoom factor, view angle, surface color mapping. Which object(s) do I have to manipulate for that? I was looking at the interfaces of vtkChartXYZ, vtkContextScene, vtkCamera, vtkRenderer, but have't found a good way to set the above parameters. What would be the best way to do this?

```
QVTKWidget vtkWidget;
vtkSmartPointer<vtkContextView> view  = vtkSmartPointer<vtkContextView>::New();
vtkSmartPointer<vtkChartXYZ>    chart = vtkSmartPointer<vtkChartXYZ>::New();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkTable> surface = vtkSmartPointer<vtkTable>::New();
// ... fill surface with some data ...

view->SetRenderWindow(vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow());
chart->SetGeometry(vtkRectf(0.0, 0.0, 300, 300));
view->GetScene()->AddItem(chart.GetPointer());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlotSurface> plot = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPlotSurface>::New();
// ... set up plot ...
plot->SetInputData(surface.GetPointer());
chart->AddPlot(plot.GetPointer());

view->GetRenderWindow()->SetMultiSamples(0);
view->GetRenderWindow()->Render();
```

Comment: For the Zoom and the view angle you move the camera.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried `view->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera()->Zoom(2.0); `view->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera()->Azimuth(30.0);` before calling Render() but nothing changed.

Comment: Still no change in appearance.

Comment: hi @bobcat , do you know how to change the surface color now?

Comment: @Steve: No, I had dropped the subject after trying for a few times.

Comment: @bobcat I did not find either. I used traditional class(vtkPoints -> vtkPolyData -> vtkDelaunay2D) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the zoom, I had the same issue and I solved by deriving the `vtkInteractorStyleImage` class, that I used for the interaction with the image in the QVTKWidget.

Basically, that class allows the zoom with the mouse wheel and, in fact, it has (among the others) the methods `OnMouseWheelForward()` and `OnMouseWheelBackward()`; but they are `private`. Deriving that class, I redefined those methods (`OnMouseWheelForward()` and `OnMouseWheelBackward()`) as `public`. Let's indicate the instance of the derived class with "`myInteractorStyle`".

This way, as soon as the image is rendered in the QVTKWidget (and `myInteractorStyle` has been assigned to the interactor) , I did something like this (assuming that you wanna increase the zoom):

```
for (int i = 0; i < zoomLevel; ++i){
   myInteractorStyle->OnMouseWheelForward();
   //Or OnMouseWheelBackward(), if you want to reduce the zoom
}
```

So, your zoom level is satisified from the beginning of the interaction. I think that, in the same way, you could solve also your other issues.